# Codeigniter static variables in model

Tags: php, codeigniter, logging, model, static

Once a user has logged in- I want all my models to know the user's id. (Even if they are called later on).

I thought about using a static variable but it doesn't seem to work

```
class Base_model extends CI_Model {
    static protected $user_id;
}

class Log_in_model extends Base_model {
    public function log_in(){
        self::$user_id = 69;
    }
}

class A_model extends Base_model {
    public function do_A(){
        echo self::$user_id;
    }
}

class B_model extends Base_model {
    public function do_B(){
        echo self::$user_id;
    }
}
```

Comment: why aren't u using session...??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

initailize session

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

after user logs in,save the userdata in session userdata

```
$newdata = array(
               'username'  => 'USERNAME',
               'email'     => 'EMAIL',
               'user_id'   => 'USERID',
               'logged_in' => TRUE
           );

$this->session->set_userdata('userdetails',$newdata);   //setting data in session with a name userdetails
```

get the session userdata..

```
 print_r($this->session->userdata('userdetails'));  //get userdetails from session
```

to destroy userdetails from session use..

```
$this->session->unset_userdata('userdetails');
```

if u want to read more about session then read this..

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: isn't it a security risk to let a user inside the system only based on session data ?

Comment: nope. You can protect it with $config['sess_encrypt_cookie'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;

Comment: @TheHorse said it all... :)